# Google Cloud Platform - Vertex AI - is there a way to look at a chart of training performance over time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'd like to know how the training performance changes over the course of the training. Is there any way to access that via Vertex AI automl service?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to see the training performance over the course of the training. Vertex AI Auto ML only shows if the training job is running or not.

The only available information is "how well did model performed with the test set after training". This can seen in the "Evaluation" tab in AutoML. You can refer to [Vertex AI Auto ML Evaluation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models) for further readings.

AutoML provides [evaluation metrics](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models#evaluation_metrics_returned_by) that could help you determine the performance of your model. Some of the evaluation metrics are precision, recall, and confidence thresholds. These vary depending on what AutoML product you are using.

For example if you have an image classification model, the following are the available evaluation metrics:

> - AuPRC: The area under the precision-recall (PR) curve, also referred to as average precision. This value ranges from zero to one, where a
>   higher value indicates a higher-quality model.
> - Log loss: The cross-entropy between the model predictions and the target values. This ranges from zero to infinity, where a lower value
>   indicates a higher-quality model.
> - Confidence threshold: A confidence score that determines which predictions to return. A model returns predictions that are at this
>   value or higher. A higher confidence threshold increases precision but
>   lowers recall. Vertex AI returns confidence metrics at different
>   threshold values to show how the threshold affects precision and
>   recall.
> - Recall: The fraction of predictions with this class that the model correctly predicted. Also called true positive rate. Precision: The
>   fraction of classification predictions produced by the model that were
>   correct.
> - Confusion matrix: A confusion matrix shows how often a model correctly predicted a result. For incorrectly predicted results, the
>   matrix shows what the model predicted instead. The confusion matrix
>   helps you understand where your model is "confusing" two results.

Answer (score 0):

[See this question with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036763/vertex-ai-training-performance-graph/). It might be what you want.