# Vertex AI - Training Performance Graph

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl, vertex-ai-pipeline

I'm looking for a graph on Vertex AI that can show me around which time the performance converged so I can present it & set the future trainings' budget (I would like to stop before the automatic early-stop).

On 2 different articles on Vertex AI, I saw a "Training performance" graph (as below). [In this medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/benchmark-your-models-6ef942e2683f) and an another in-company article written by an employee who left the company since. I see no directions to access this graph and no mention of it anywhere else except [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70175440/6535119) which suggests it doesn't exist

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051655/vertex-ai-how-to-monitor-training-progress) which is about monitoring from logs, but I'm convinced that a graph exists somewhere.

How do I see this Training performance graph, under which menu is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi degemenc, Does this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/overview) will help you ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, what I was looking for doesn't require any extra steps to the simple Vertex AI flow. I added an answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help from [the writer of the Medium article](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7060954/guenter), we were able to discover:

This graph is visible in the training details page, which is easily accessible by clicking on the training while under "Trainings" menu.

However, after a training is completed, clicking on it keeps redirecting to "Model Registry" menu, which doesn't show the graph.

I had to force my completed training's ID into training details link and see the Training page along with the graph.

`https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/locations/{LOC}/training/{TRAINING_ID}`

[image]